# Rigidity in a $CAT(-1)$ space

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

**Summary**: How to proove that a reunion of triangles in a
$CAT(-1)$ space is isometric to the reunion of coresponding
comparisons triangles ?

**Context and notations:**

Le $X$ be a $CAT(-1)$ metric space.
Let $\left( y_{i}\right)_{i=1, \dots, n}$
be points in $X$ and $x$ their center of mass.
We denote by $T_{i}$ the geodesic triangle with vertices
$(y_{i}, x, y_{i+1})$
and $\tilde{T_{i}}$ the corresponding
comparison triangle in $\mathbb{H}^{2}$,
with vertices
$(\tilde{y_{i}}, \tilde{x}, \tilde{y_{i+1}})$
.

Let $\alpha_{i}$ be the angle
of $T_{i}$ at the vertex $x$
and $\tilde{\alpha_{i}}$
the angle of $\tilde{T_{i}}$ at the vertex $\tilde{x}$.

We denote by $\Sigma_x X$ the space of directions
at $x$ and by $C_x X$ the tangent cone at $x$.
We denote by $<c_1, c_2>$ the "inner product" on $C_x X$.

**Fact:**
Because $x$ is the center of mass of $(y_i)$
we have:
$ \sum_i \alpha_i \ge 2 \pi$.

**Problem:**
Suppose now that
$ \sum_i \tilde{\alpha_i} = 2 \pi$.
Is the union $\bigcup_i T_i$
isometric to the gluing of the hyperbolic
triangles $\bigcup_i \tilde{T_i}$ ?

**What I did:**

The hypothesis implies that
$\tilde{\alpha_i} = \alpha_i$
and so each triangle $T_i$ is
individually isometric to $\tilde{T_i}$.
I prooved that it is then enough to show
that
$\alpha_i + \alpha_{i+1} =
\angle_x (y_i, y_{i+2})$
for $T_i \cup T_{i+1}$ to be
isometric to $\tilde{T_i} \cup \tilde{T_{i+1}}$.
So I interpreted the problem in the space of directions:
Let $P$ be the geodesic polygon in $\Sigma_x X$
with vertices $p_i = [x, y_i]$ the class of the
geodesic going from $x$ to $y_i$.
My problem is now equivalent to: is $P$
a closed geodesic ?

**What could be useful:**

The fact that $x$ is the center of mass
of the $(y_i)$
implies that
for every non-trivial geodesic $v$ starting
at $x$:
$ \sum_i d(x, y_i) \cos \angle (v, p_i) \le 0$.

A "short loop" theorem: a closed (geodesic polygonal) curve
in a $CAT(1)$, whose length is less than $2 \pi$ is contained
in a ball of radius $\pi/2$

All of my definitions are from "Metric spaces of non-positive curvature"
by Bridson and Haefliger but feel free to ask me to precise something.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is true.

Note that the directions to the triangles at $x$, say $\gamma$, form a closed geodesic in $\Sigma_x$. 
If not one could short it a bit, apply Reshetnyak's majorization for $\gamma$ in $\Sigma_x$ and pass to the limit --- this way you get a short map from a convex polygon (which has to be digon since its perimeter is $2\cdot\pi$) to $\Sigma_x$ which is path isometric on the boundary. 
It follows that for some point $z$ we have $\measuredangle[x^{y_i}_z]\le \tfrac\pi2$ and for some $i$ the inequality is strict.
The latter contradicts that $x$ is the barycenter.

Once it is done apply exponential map in the direction of $\gamma$ and your argument shows that it is isometry until the end of triangles.

(I assumed above without saying that $\Sigma_x$ is locally compact, but it is generalizable using ultralimits.)

Comment: More generally, you may think of it as a rigidity case in Kirszbraun's theorem --- it gives existence of isometric copy of of convex hyperbolic polyhedron in your space.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Some things are still unclear: why the inequality would be strict for some $i$ ? where do you use the local compacity ? Could you also explained how this is related to Kirzsbraun's theorem ? I've looked at your paper about this theorem but didn't find a rigidity case.

Comment: 1. since the majorizer is digon, it contains a point on distance $<\tfrac\pi2$ from all but two points in the digon.

Comment: 2. There is 1+n lemma and it has a rigidity case, this is not in the paper, but it is easy to prove --- simply take the map provided by Kirszbraun theorem and check that it is distance preserving on the convex hull of $\{y_i\}$.

Comment: 1. Is it clear that the majorizer can't be a great circle ?

Comment: @FlorentinMB (You wanted to say "half-sphere".) Take point $x$ at which $\gamma$ has angle.  Do smaller and smaller short cuts near $x$ and pass to the limit of memorizer. Note that the limit has angle at the point corresponding to $x$.

Comment: I've come back to this problem and given it a lot of thought, but I still don't understand your explanation. You say: "Note that the limit has angle at the point corresponding to $x$". I don't see why that would be true. You seem to be saying that if a curve has an angle then a majorizer should too, but it is false for example if one majorizes a digon by a half-sphere.